# How can I find all rows with time values between those on other rows?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to make a SQL query that gathers all events that happen during a 'c4' event. In other words, I would like to get all rows that have a startTime or endTime during a c4.

| eventId | machineId | startTime | endTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a3 | 1 | 9:19 | 9:41 |
| c4 | 1 | 9:15 | 9:42 |
| a9 | 1 | 9:16 | 9:18 |
| b3 | 1 | 9:40 | 9:46 |
| j5 | 1 | 9:51 | 9:52 |
| g6 | 2 | 9:57 | 9:59 |

In this table above, I would expect a3, a9 and b3 to be returned.

My attempt is below but I don't know how to differentiate between the time of the row being checked or the time of the c4 row.

```
COUNTIF(
    eventId = 'c4' 
    AND UNIX_SECONDS(startTime) > UNIX_SECONDS(startTime) 
    AND UNIX_SECONDS(endTime) < UNIX_SECONDS(endTime)) OVER (
        PARTITION BY machineId
) AS is_during_c4
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     t tc4
     on (t.starttime between tc4.starttime and tc4.endtime or
         t.endtime between tc4.starttime and tc4.endtime
        ) and
        tc4.eventid = 'c4';
```

Note that what is usually needed in this case is any *overlap*, and the above logic does not capture:

```
C4         -----XXXXXXX------
A9         --AAAAAAAAAAAA----
```

For this, the logic is:

```
select t.*
from t join
     t tc4
     on t.starttime < =tc4.endtime and
        t.endtime >= tc4.starttime and
        tc4.eventid = 'c4';
```

Comment: Thanks. So basically I left join a c4 event based on overlapping start and end times?

Comment: @mongoose132 . . . Yes, that is the idea.